# Android/iOS client consumes WCF Duplex service

Tags: android, ios, wcf, web-services, duplex

I am trying to build a server/web service which provides APIs to Android/iOS client. I am using WCF service and clients can send request to server successfully. Now, I am going to make server enable to ping client to notify that there some changes in server and client need to synchronize data.

The question is: Is it possible to enable my server to ping client (Android/iOS), I knew that it is possible for Windows client by using wsDualHttpBinding but I am not sure about iOS and Android client. Anyone can help me to make it clear? Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. For start, while wsDualHttpBinding is intended to be interoperable I don't beleive in practice it is supported by any otehr framework than WCF. Then wsDualHttpBinding uses a [client callback url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.clientbaseaddress.aspx) that the server needs to contact. This url is not going to be accessible on a phone. You should use websockets, long polling or some proprietary push mechanism of the device os.